# Prestashop webservice authentication

Tags: android, web-services, prestashop-1.6

I'm going to develop android application for PrestaShop 1.6
I want to allow merchants update their products and stuff like this. Prestashop provides a webservice and a key for basic HTTP authentication to access webservice, details are available at http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Using+the+PrestaShop+Web+Service. 
However I want to authenticate my merchants to before allowing them to access webservice.
I want to know how this pre-authetication is possible?
Note: may be I'm wrong and should use this access key as authentication key, however please correct me if I'm thinking in wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you will have to create your own simple authentication system and then give access to users.